# conditional props to react typescript component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics, tsx

I'm building a react component that takes a structure and a value argument

```
interface OptionFieldProps {
    structure: { name: string; multi: boolean };
    value: string | string[] | undefined;
}
```

where if multi is true value is of type `string[] | undefined` and if its false value is of type `string | undefined`. I've tried using generics to show this relationship...

```
type FieldValue <T extends { name: string; multi: boolean }> = 
    T extends { multi: true } ? string[] | undefined : string | undefined

interface OptionFieldProps <T extends { name: string; multi: boolean }> {
    structure: T;
    value: FieldValue<T>;
}
```

But when I pass that to the component it says the type of value is always `string | undefined`

```
class OptionField extends Component<OptionFieldProps<{ name: string; multi: boolean }>>{
    render(){
        const { structure, value } = this.props
        //value: string | undefined
    }
}
```

How should I write this so typescript will understand this relationship?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve it with a union type for your props with a specific type for *single* and a specific type for *multi*.

Example:

```
interface SingleProps {
  structure: { name: string; multi: false };
  value?: string;
}

interface MultiProps {
  structure: { name: string; multi: true };
  value?: string[];
}

type MyProps = SingleProps | MultiProps;

const MyComponent = (props: MyProps) => {
  const { value } = props; // string | string[] | undefined
  return <div>...</div>;
}
```

Comment: this works great until I have to do something like {structure.multi ? <div>...</div> : <div>...</div>} any idea on how I can fix that?

Comment: That should work... what are you trying to there precisely and what is the problem?